# SOLR Mappling an accented character to multiple values

Tags: solr

We are working on expanding an implementation of Solr to international markets.  The `mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt` only supports one mapping per accented characters.  For example: `ä => a`.  However we want to map `ä => a` and `ae`.  Is there a way to map 1 accented character to multiple non-accented representations in the existing ISO mapping or do we need a custom mapper?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feels a little bit like reinventing a bicycle. If you are planning to deal with international markets, switch up from using simple mapping to using ICU Unicode Mapping.

Solr has a full support for Unicode normalization, decomposition, and mapping components ([search for those starting from ICU](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/)). It takes a little bit of exploring, but is well worth it.